# How do I let whole DIV can be click and redirect to next page

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I want to make a whole `DIV` can be clicked and redirect to next page. How do I edit this code. I am new in `MVC`

Here is my `MVC` 5 code:

```css
.defaultpage_menu  {
cursor:pointer;
text-decoration:none;
color:white;
}

.defaultpage_menu:hover{
text-decoration:none;
color:black;
}

.defaultpage_menu_button{
width:50%; 
height:50%; 
}

.default_menu_title  {
margin:25% 30% 25% 35%;
font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<a>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 defaultpage_menu_button" id="defaultpage_menu_userlisting">
        <h1 class="default_menu_title">@Html.ActionLink("User Listing", "Index", "UserTables", new { area = "" }, new { @class = " defaultpage_menu" })</h1>
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: You can attach a href to your anchor tag which calls the controller and action method using Url.Action() method helper

Comment: You can use javascript to handle the `.click()` event of the `<div>` and redirect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index","UserTables")" class="defaultpage_menu">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6       defaultpage_menu_button" id="defaultpage_menu_userlisting">
            <h1 class="default_menu_title">User Listing</h1>
        </div>
    </a>
```

Comment: Thx it slove my problem!

Comment: Good to hear it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with jQuery (or, well, Javascript)

```
$("div").click(function(){

    window.location.replace("http://your.next.page/");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try It Once

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.link').click(function(){
  window.location = "http://www.google.com/"; 
});
});
```

```css
.link{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid #ff9900;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="link">Click me</div>
```